# How to calculate probability for Bose-Einstein scenarios?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How do we calculate probability when we are doing an experiment with replacement and when the order does not matter? For example, let us assume we are drawing 4 cards from a deck of 52 cards with replacement and the order of the 4 cards drawn does not matter. Now, how to find the probability that the drawn set of 4 cards contains exactly two cards from diamond suit?

Comment: Hi, thank you for response. I am aware of counting under this scenario. How to calculate probability? So, the total possibilities by counting is  (n+k−1 C k). However these possibilities are not equally likely and cannot be used in calculating probabilities.

Comment: Referring to Bose-Einstein here is a wee bit of overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

You are right that stars and bars does not give equiprobable results, and can't be used here.

But the problem can be easily converted to a binomial distribution by dividing cards into $13$ diamonds and $39$ non-diamonds.

You should be able to proceed from here.

**Re your comment**

The binomial distribution will compute the probability taking into account all possible orders.

If you want the probability of some *particular* order, say one diamond folloed by two non-diamonds followed by a diamond,

$Pr = \frac14\frac34\frac34\frac14$ which you can, of course condense, as $(\frac14)^2(\frac34)^2$

This computation will represent *one* of the $\binom42$ orders that the binomial coefficient gave.

Comment: In this case, is the correct answer then (4 C 2) 〖1/4〗^2 〖3/4〗^2 ~0.2109.. How do you then calculate for similar situation but when the order matters. Could you explain how to calculate probability in that situation? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have added in the answer

Comment: Thank you. Is it fair to then say the probability of drawing exactly 2 diamond cards when 4 cards are drawn from a deck of 52 cards when the order matters is greater than the probability of drawing exactly 2 diamond cards when 4 cards are drawn from a deck of 52 cards when order does not matter by a factor of (4 C 2)?

Comment: "Order matters/order does not matter" are unfortunately susceptible to different interpretations. I prefer to say that when all possible orders are considered, the $Pr$ is $^4C_2$ times greater than when a particular order is considered.